# Change Excel Pivot Table Data Source from one worksheet to another in a formula (a no click solution)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to use an indirect type function or a custom function to set the pivot range without having to click 'Change Data Source' under PivotTable Analyze in the ribbon. A no click solution if you will.

I have a Pivot Table in one sheet and multiple worksheets that have identical columns, each worksheet represents a different years worth of data. I set each worksheet as an Excel Table and gave it a name to have the dynamic range. Now I'd like to put the range name in a cell or create a dropdown in the PivotTable sheet that selects the data source for the pivot table in a formula, dynamically updating the pivot table data source.

I see there is a way to change the PivotTable data source in VBA if it's worksheet data, which this is.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache _
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Table2", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)
```

But MS documentation says statements that select and format ranges, are excluded from custom functions. Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Comment: Just enter your Named Range in the `Table/Range` box of `Change Data Source`, for example *MyDataSource*, where *MyDataSource* is defined in Name Manager as `=INDIRECT($G$1)` where `G1` contains either *Table1* or *Table2*, for example. Of course, a Pivot Table refresh will still be required to see any changes.

Comment: Works like a charm. Please post as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Added as an answer.

Comment: See my response below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enter your Named Range in the `Table/Range` box of `Change Data Source`, for example *MyDataSource*, where *MyDataSource* is defined in Name Manager as `=INDIRECT($G$1)` where `G1` contains either *Table1* or *Table2*, for example.

Of course, a Pivot Table refresh will still be required to see any changes

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Perhaps ask @rew?

Comment: For my particular needs - The Pivot Table is the First Sheet. I download a CSV containing annual data from a cloud provider so its the same date range. I then move it to the Pivot workbook and run a Macro to format the data sheets EXACTLY alike, and also make it an Excel Table for the dynamic range. Now with the answer I obtained on this question, I can change the name on the Pivot sheet and point to the new data.

As the answer pointed out, it's not a "no click" solution since I still have to refresh the data, but it's close enough for my needs. Hope that helps.